# How do I run org.mozilla.firefox from Flathub as a native Wayland client?

Tags: linux, configuration, firefox, wayland, flatpak

I installed org.mozilla.firefox from Flathub, and upon investigating with `xeyes`, I found that it seems to be running via XWayland as the eyes are able to trace my cursor when hovering over Firefox. I'm using GNOME via Wayland, and I would like to run Firefox as a native Wayland client instead of running it via XWayland. How might I do this with the org.mozilla.firefox package from Flathub? I am **not** interested in using my distribution's package instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by setting the environment variable MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND to 1 and allowing org.mozilla.firefox to access the Wayland socket via `flatpak override`.

Something like this:

```
$ flatpak override --env=MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1 --socket=wayland org.mozilla.firefox --user
```

You can omit `--user` if you want to do this for all users.

If you prefer to do this graphically, you can use Flatseal: https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal

Answer (score 0):

On fedora linux override command did not worked for me.
I just executed with command

```
flatpak --env=MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=1  run org.mozilla.firefox
```